# Xamarin Forms InitializeComponent does not exist

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin Forms for Visual Studio 2015 and trying to create a simple Shared project using Xaml but I keep getting InitializeComponent does not exist (as well as any reference to Xaml controls in cs classes).

It is my understanding that in the latest versions of Xamarin, Xaml works in Shared Xamarin Forms Projects (and not only in PCL projects). I've tried running the latest betas that got released less than a month ago but still no luck.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share XAML and CS files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out I had to manually change the properties for all Xaml files like so:

```
Build Action: Embedded resource
Custom Tool: MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml
```

For some reason adding new Xaml forms files doesn't set these by default in VS2015 with latest Xamarin.

Comment: If this happens to you, it may be also worth it to unload the `.csproj` file and check if you have conflicting/redundant `<RemoveItem>` and `<ItemGroup>` tags for these `.xaml` / `.xaml.cs` files. If so, just delete them all (VS imports all files and folders within the solution/project folder by default, these tags are used only when you want to display files in VS differently than the actual project structure).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. And it turned out to be that fully qualified Class Name (`x:Class` attribute in the main node) in the XAML file must match exactly the xaml.cs file's name. I corrected the namespace casing and it worked!!

Answer (score 3):

This happens when your XAML markup is invalid. There is a background compilation task that parses the XAML file and generates a code file (this is normally hidden from the developer) which declares those control references. If your XAML is not valid then this task will fail silently, and your first hints are the symptoms you describe.

Comment out the contents of your XAML file using standard XML comment syntax (wrap it with `<!--` and `-->`), then rebuild your project to clear out all of the errors. You may also need to comment out some code in your .cs files temporarily to get it to build. Once you get it building, then you can go back and start uncommenting your XAML until you find the part that was breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it: 
Open the Package Manager Console, put the follow line:
update-package -project your_pcl_project_name -reinstall