# Xamarin - How to troubleshoot "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context" errors?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin development, and while developing my first app, I hit the error "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context".

Searching the web gave a bunch of results suggesting rolling back the Xamarin.Forms package, rebuilding packages, closing and re-opening VS, cleaning and re-building. None of them helped.

How can I determine the cause of the error?

Comment: Earliest existing SO answer I can find that says this is [This happens when your XAML markup is invalid...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659516/199364). This answer is sufficiently buried (under completely unrelated suggestions) that I'm not going to vote to close this question as a duplicate (although technically it is). Upvoted. Its good to have it easier to find a solution to this common problem!

Answer (score 1):

After a while I understood, that InitializeComponent is defined in the auto-generated C# file MyPage.xaml.g.cs. If the method is not there, it means code generation failed.
I guess there may be a thousand reasons, in my case it was a mistaken type name in the .xaml file:

```
<ContentPage
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="Waiter.Xmrn.Views.MyPage666"
...
```

The actual class name was ...MyPage.

Unfortunately, I had no other messages - hopefully in the fuure there's going to be something more specific.